# How to Silence Node.js Debugger Messages in Visual Studio Code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, node-debugger

Whenever I run a Node.js project in Visual Studio Code, the following messages are displayed in the terminal:

```
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:53142/6203fcf4-5860-4fae-9203-340b57f67547
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.

...

Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

Depending on the complexity of my project, sometimes these messages are displayed several times. They clutter the console and make important messages more difficult to find.

How can I silence these messages?